# check whether user going without placing order in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to keep track for my magento store whether any user going without placing order and close the tab i want suggestion from him or her is it possible or not . Can any one have idea . I am totally confuse where to start.

Comment: no need for answer. If you do not know it is ok but do not make minus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the details of not order user from magento default maintain this user reports,

```
Reports -> Shopping Carts -> Abandoned carts
```